# Diassemble DLL written in VB,C,C++

Tags: .net

I have a few DLLs which are written in VB COM, C, and C++. How can I disassemble those DLL?
Please consider that the dlls are written in VB,C,C++.

Thanks for reply.
Jaydeep

Comment: Native or .Net? I know you have used the `.net` tag, but you mention VB COM (meaning VB6 and before?) and C, which makes me think your tag is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

With any decent disassembler, the flagship product obviously being [IDA](http://www.hex-rays.com/idapro/). If you are talking about a recent version of Visual Basic (i.e. .NET-enabled, which I doubt though), [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) would be the tool of choice. Applications created with older versions of Visual Basic can be examined using NuMega SmartCheck which is currently out of production, and also more of a debugger, but with better insight into the old VB object model.

Comment: Olly is more of an interactive debugger. And while IDA also offers debugging features, you cannot create a dead listing using Olly.